# How to run Python class method spausdinti if the object initiated as follows obj = Objektas()?

Tags: python, class, methods

How to run class method spausdinti if the object initiated as follows
obj = Objektas() ?

```
class Objektas:
    def spausdinti(self):
        print("Spausdinama")
```

Which answer is correct?

```
a obj.spausdinti()
b spausdinti()
c Objektas.spausdinti()
```

Comment: Any reason you didn't just try in your python command line prompt?

Answer (score 1):

None of these options are correct.
Since the `spausdinti` method is a class bound method, you first have to create an instance of the `Objektas` class. With that instance, you can call the `spausdinti` method.

```py
objektas_instance = Objektas()  # Create an instance
objektas_instance.spausdinti()  # Call the method. The `self` object
```

in the method will be a reference to the `objektas_instance` instance

EDIT: I should note that option `C` is very close, but it's missing the extra `()` to create an instance of `Objektas`. Doing `Objektas().spausdinti()` would also work.